# Исправить запрос select

Tags: sql, select, where

```sql
select id, birthdate 
from Users 
where chief_id = NULL
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Когда значение NULL, то надо указывать не `=`, а `IS NULL`:

```
SELECT id, birthdate FROM Users WHERE chief_id IS NULL
```

Если же надо выбрать все ненулевые значения, то:

```
SELECT id, birthdate FROM Users WHERE chief_id IS NOT NULL
```

Comment: @IVShII Ну если надо выбрать все ненулевые значения, то IS NOT NULL используется)
Не за что, если вопрос решен, не забудьте выделить ответ галочкой, чтоб закрыть вопрос)

Comment: Спасибо большое. Надеюсь решение верно))

Comment: @IVShII не за что) Все должно быть верно) Буду признателен если пометите мой ответ как правильный)